# Sending an array with AJAX removes its values

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I get an array of attributes that need to be included in a INPUT in a database. So i use AJAX to send that array to a php file that does the INPUT part. The problem is that the array is empty when it gets to the php file. I have checked the values of the array before sending it, and they are all right. I also entered those values manually into the php code and it worked fine.
Here is the AJAX code and the php:

```
$.ajax ({type:"GET", url:"input.php", data:attr});


<?php
$attr = $_GET["attr"];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ucenici");
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ucenici() VALUES(NULL, '$attr[1]', '$attr[2]', '$attr[3]', '$attr[4]', '$attr[5]', '$attr[6]', '$attr[7]', '$attr[8]', '$attr[9]', '$attr[10]', '$attr[11]', '$attr[12]', '$attr[13]', '$attr[14]', '$attr[15]', '$attr[16]', '$attr[17]', '$attr[18]', '$attr[19]', '$attr[20]', '$attr[21]')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: I am not sure you can get it like this. Variable attr is javascript json object. Try to take it one by one, something like this $attr = $_GET["one of the parameters in attr variable"]

Comment: You can actually, i fixed it. But I just added data by data: {data: attr}. And used data[0], data[1],... in my input. Don't know if that fixed it or I just missed a semicolon somewhere